# Object with Date is saved with the wrong date and format

Tags: php, symfony, datepicker, symfony-forms, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm saving a date with Symfony 3 and the [bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

If I fill out my form I expect it to save a date, 04/25/2017 in this case.

What I want in my datatabse is this: **04/25/2017.**

Instead I get this in my dump:

> 2017-01-25 00:04.000000

and in my database:

> 2017-**01**-25

**Dump result:**

[image]

**Database value:**

[image]

**PlayLogController:**

```
    <?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\PlayLog;
use AppBundle\Entity\Game;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * Playlog controller.
 *
 * @Route("playlog")
 */
class PlayLogController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Lists all playLog entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="playlog_index")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $playLogs = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:PlayLog')->findAll();

        return $this->render('playlog/index.html.twig', array(
            'playLogs' => $playLogs,
        ));
    }
    /**
     * Creates a new playLog entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{gameId}/new", name="playlog_new")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request, $gameId)
    {
        $playlog = new PlayLog();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $game = $em ->getRepository(Game::class)->find($gameId);
        $playlog->setGame($game);
        $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\PlayLogType', $playlog);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            /* @var $playLog PlayLog */
            $playlog = $form->getData();
           // echo $playlog->getGame()->getId() .'!';

            $em->persist($playlog);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->render('playlog/new.html.twig', array(
            'playLog' => $playlog,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
    /**
     * Finds and displays a playLog entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="playlog_show")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function showAction(PlayLog $playLog)
    {
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($playLog);
        return $this->render('playlog/show.html.twig', array(
            'playLog' => $playLog,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing playLog entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="playlog_edit")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request, PlayLog $playLog)
    {
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($playLog);
        $editForm = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\PlayLogType', $playLog);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('playlog_edit', array('id' => $playLog->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('playlog/edit.html.twig', array(
            'playLog' => $playLog,
            'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a playLog entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="playlog_delete")
     * @Method("DELETE")
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, PlayLog $playLog)
    {
        $form = $this->createDeleteForm($playLog);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->remove($playLog);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('playlog_index');
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to delete a playLog entity.
     *
     * @param PlayLog $playLog The playLog entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createDeleteForm(PlayLog $playLog)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('playlog_delete', array('id' => $playLog->getId())))
            ->setMethod('DELETE')
            ->getForm()
        ;
    }
}
```

**PlayLogType:**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use AppBundle\Entity\PlayLog;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class PlayLogType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('date', DateType::class, array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'html5' => false,
            'attr' => ['class' => 'js-datepicker'],
            'format' => 'mm/dd/yyyy'
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => PlayLog::class
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_playlog';
    }


}
```

**The script I use for the datepicker:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.js-datepicker').datepicker({
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Format must be `'MM/dd/yyyy'`. `mm` are minutes, which is why the time is `00:04` in your record.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, it looks better but I still dont't get this result: 04/25/2017, instead I now get this: 2017-04-25, which is almost what I want except for the year, I want that at the end.

Comment: That's the same date but formatted differently. I'm guessing there's a setting in your mysql client that might change the displayed date format.

Answer (score 0):

The date/time format that you send to the server is going to depend on the locale that the server is in. Since I see Europe/Berlin in your screenshot above that means it's expecting the date/time to come in as d/m/Y (php format).

Alternatively the best way to eliminate all the date/time formats is to send it in either YYYY-MM-DD H:i:s format (H:i:s can be omitted if you don't care about time), or as a unix timestamp which is guaranteed to be in UTC time..